# Ruby: Remove all instances of a duplicate value inside an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

I have one array and I want to remove ALL instances of a duplicate value inside of that array.

`arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]`

I want the expected output:

`=> [2, 3, 5]`

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
p arr.group_by(&:itself).reject{|k,v|v.count>1}.keys
```

Output

```
[2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are three ways that could be done (@Rajagopalan's answer being another).

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

**Use a counting hash**

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }.select { |_,v| v == 1 }.keys
  # => [2, 3, 5]
```

**Use [Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-count)**

```
arr.uniq.select { |n| arr.count(n) == 1 }
  #=> [2, 3, 5]
```

This may seem relatively inefficient considering that `arr` must be traversed for each element of `arr.uniq`. If `arr.uniq` is not too large, however, it actually may be faster than using a counting hash or (as Rajagopalan has done) [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

**Use [Array#difference](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815)**

`Array#difference` is a method I have suggested be added to the Ruby core.

```
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end
```

If we had use of that method we could write the following.

```
arr - arr.difference(arr.uniq)
  #=> [2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: `arr.each_with_object({}) { |e, h| h[e] = !h[e] & 0}.select{|_,v| v }.keys`

Comment: @Ingo, if `arr = [1,1,1]`, `[1]` is returned (because, for  a given `e`, `h[e] = !h[e] & 0` alternates between `0` and  `false`).

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
arr.reject{|x| arr.count(x)>1}
```

expected output

```
=> [2, 3, 5]
```

**if it's a Multi-dimensional**

```
multi_array = [[33], [34], [35], [34, 35], [34, 35], [36], [30, 31], [30, 31], [30, 31, 32], [32, 33]] 
multi_flatten = multi_array.flatten
#=> [33, 34, 35, 34, 35, 34, 35, 36, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 32, 32, 33]
multi_flatten.reject{|x| multi_flatten.count(x)>1}
#=> [36]
```

Comment: Please add context to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler solution:

arr = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6]

new_arr = arr - [1]

new_arr returns [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

+1 for: arr.uniq.select { |n| arr.count(n) == 1 } seems to be more readable and clean

@cary-swoveland Array#difference seem to have some performance issue.

Answer (score -2):

https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/uniq

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
arr.uniq
```

returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This gives unique values yes, but I want to remove ALL unique values.

Comment: My bad - above answer from @Rajagopalan seems more accurate

Comment: Yeah he wanted to remove the duplicate elements